# Example regarding the difference quotient

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

Give an example of a differentiable function $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $f^\prime(0) = 1$, but there are no points $x,z \in \mathbb{R}$ for which $\frac{f(x)-f(z)}{x-z}=1$ and $x \neq z$. Would $f(x)=x$ work?

Comment: If $f(x)=x$, then $\dfrac{f(x)-f(z)}{x-z} = 1$, we do not want $\dfrac{f(x)-f(z)}{x-z} = 1$.

Comment: I thought that was what we want. No two x-values are the same and the slope between them must be 1.

Comment: No. I believe you got confused because of the double negative in the sentence. What we want is if $x\neq z$, then $\dfrac{f(x) -f(z)}{x-z} \neq 1$ and $f'(0) = 1$.

Comment: For two points on the line $f(x) = x$, we have $\dfrac{f(x)-f(z)}{x-z}  = 1$, which is what we **do not want**.

Comment: @user17762. I see. Would (1/2)x^2 + x work. F'(x) = x +1 so f'(0) = 1 and the difference quotient is not 1.

Comment: Yes, that would clearly work.

Comment: Yeah you were right I got confused in the sentence. Thanks